# magento can't reindex product attributes

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

When I run Reindex from Index Management it gives error **"Cannot initialize the indexer process."**

So based on following article here 
http://jasonehmke.com/ecommerce/cannot-initialize-the-indexer-process-in-magento/

I ran

```
php -f indexer.php reindexall
```

Which gave following output:

```
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully
Product Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully
Category Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully

Product Attributes index process unknown error:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '65-542-1-65' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /home/bizzosph/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '65-542-1-65' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /home/bizzosph/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
```

Any idea how do I fix this? It does not tell me what table has duplicate entry.

Thanks

Comment: I actually had a similar issue happen to me. I was able to fix it by deleting all of the `.locks` files from the `var/locks` folder and then deleting (`trunacate`) all the rows in the table `catalog_flat_product_1` and finally running the indexer again.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm sure you've moved on since posting this question, but since it has ~2500 views (and having this answer here would have helped me), I'll add the resolution I found.  **This does not require truncating any database tables or even any direct SQL queries**:*

Last night, I was having the same problem. My error was the same as yours (except for the numbers which refer to the product and attribute causing the problem).  If you go and re-save that product in the Manage Products section of the admin (no need to change it, just open it to edit and click save), it will solve the problem - but you very likely have more products that will bring additional similar errors.

In my case, it wasn't just a problem with 1 product there were several hundred products causing errors (each one saved brought up a new one). And it wasn't all with the same attribute (I'd updated multiple attributes across a database of over 4,000 products in my last import).

Since everything seemed to actually be in the database correctly (since re-saving seemed to be fixing it and giving the proper data to the final saved product), I had an idea.

Why not export all 4k products, and then re-import the same file without modification and see if that clears it.

It worked!

**tl;dr: If you're having this problem with multiple products needing to be re-saved, export your whole inventory (or the relevant section if you can segment in a useful way), and re-import the same file with no modifications.**

I'm using Magento v 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try first to clean Magento cache. If no success, run [official DB repair tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run the following MySQL queries:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_flat_1`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_flat_2`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_flat_3`;
```